# K-Means Algorithm not working properly

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I was trying to write my own K-Means clustering algorithm however it is not working.Can someone take a look and help me finding what mistake I am committing.I am fairly new.

I expect the data to be clustered in 2 groups since K=2.However I am not getting the expected result.I think mean assignment is not working properly.Can someone give a look?

https://github.com/DivJ/Robo_Lab/blob/master/K_Means.py

```
dist=[]
lab=[]
x_sum,y_sum=0,0
x_sum1,y_sum1=0,0
k=2  
mean=pt[:k]

def assignment():
   global dist
   global lab
   for i in range(0,100):
     for j in range(0,k):
        dist.append(math.hypot(pt[i,0]-mean[j,0],pt[i,1]-mean[j,1]))
    lab.append(dist.index(min(dist)))
    dist=[]

def mean_shift():
  global x_sum,x_sum1,y_sum,y_sum1,lab
  for i in range(0,100):
    if(lab[i]==0):
        plt.scatter(pt[i,0],pt[i,1],c='r')
        x_sum=pt[i,0]+x_sum
        y_sum=pt[i,1]+y_sum

    elif(lab[i]==1):
        plt.scatter(pt[i,0],pt[i,1],c='b')
        x_sum1=pt[i,0]+x_sum1
        y_sum1=pt[i,1]+y_sum1

   mean[0,0]=x_sum/lab.count(0)
   mean[0,1]=y_sum/lab.count(0)
   mean[1,0]=x_sum1/lab.count(1)
   mean[1,1]=y_sum1/lab.count(1)
   lab=[]




def k_means(itr):
  for z in range(0,itr):
    assignment()
    mean_shift()

k_means(100)
```

Comment: Please paste the code here directly, it is short enough. Please also explain what exactly is "not working".

Comment: Code added for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's wrong with your code:

1) You initialize `means` as `pt[:k]`, however later you reassign `means` which leads to the first two points being reassigned unintentionally since `means` merely is a pointer to these points. You need to create a copy of the first to points to avoid changing them:

```
import copy
means=copy.copy(pt[:k])
```

2) You initialize `x_sum, y_sum, x_sum1` and `y_sum1` outside of `mean_shift()` which causes the sums to grow bigger and bigger with each iteration. Set them to 0 every time you call `mean_shift()`.